# Filter syslog in php functions, then display contents in JS div?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, regex, syslog

Let's revise this question with a new approach...I have three files: logtail.php, ajax.js and index.php. My goal is to create a syslog viewer (Linux).

On index.php I made a div where I want to display only the filtered contents of the syslog. I must filter the contents in logtail.php. I have to use a shell_exec and | grep the contents with multiple different regexes. Right now I | grep the entire syslog file and it displays live in the log viewer, but my filters are not working as planned.

I need help figuring out how to use $_GET to grab only the contents from the syslog that the user wants to see. I have a text field and submit button prepared for that in my index.php file. Should I use functions (tried this already)? Or is there a better approach? Can you give me some examples?

logtail.php

```
//Executes a shell script to grab all file contents from syslog on the device
//Explodes that content into an array by new line, sorts from most recent entry to oldest entry

if (file_exists($filename = '/var/log/syslog')) {
    $syslogContent = shell_exec("cat $filename | grep -e '.*' $filename");
    $contentArray = explode("\n", $syslogContent);
    rsort($contentArray);
    print_r($contentArray);
}
```

ajax.js (working properly)

```
function createRequest() {
    var request = null;
    try {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (trymicrosoft) {
        try {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (othermicrosoft) {
            try {
                request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (failed) {
                request = null;
            }
        }
    }

    if (request == null) {
        return alert("Error creating request object!");
    } else {
        return request;
    }
}

var request = createRequest();

function getLog(timer) {
    var url = 'logtail.php';
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.onreadystatechange = updatePage;
    request.send(null);
    startTail(timer);
}

function startTail(timer) {
    if (timer == "stop") {
        stopTail();
    } else {
        t = setTimeout("getLog()",1000);
    }
}

function stopTail() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    var pause = "The log viewer has been paused. To begin viewing again, click the Start Log button.\n";
    logDiv = document.getElementById("log");
    var newNode = document.createTextNode(pause);
    logDiv.replaceChild(newNode,logDiv.childNodes[0]);
}

function updatePage() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200) {
            var currentLogValue = request.responseText.split("\n");
            eval(currentLogValue);
            logDiv = document.getElementById("log");
            var logLine = ' ';
            for (i = 0; i < currentLogValue.length - 1; i++) {
                logLine += currentLogValue[i] + "<br/>\n";
            }
            logDiv.innerHTML = logLine;
        } else
            alert("Error! Request status is " + request.status);
    }
}

index.php

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/ajax.js"></script>
        <button style="margin-left:25px;" onclick="getLog('start');">Start Log</button>
        <button onclick="stopTail();">Stop Log</button>
            <form action="" method="get"> //This is where the filter options would be
                Date & Time (ex. Nov 03 07:24:57): <input type="text" name="dateTime" />
                <input type="submit" value="submit" />
            </form>
    <br>
    <div id="log" style="...">
    //This is where the log contents are displayed
    </div>
```

Comment: So have you even tried to code the ajax.js page? Whay are you including logtail.php as javascript?  I don't see any javascript output in logtail.php, nor anything in logtail.php that would actually execute the function shown.

Comment: @MikeBrant yes I tried to code it but couldn't get it to call my php function from logtail.php. I need the function to display its contents in the div on index.php. I don't know where to start with that which is why I am asking

Comment: @MikeBrant I just added my code for ajax.js but I can't even begin to tell you how bad it is ha

Comment: You can start by showing the AJAX code, since that is the main thing you are concerned with.  Also, you still haven't answered teh question on why you have this `<script type="text/javascript" src="logtail.php"></script>` in your HTML.  It doens't make sense that this would both output some javascript code (which it doesn't seem to do from your code example) and that it would be the endpoint for delivering content to an AJAX call.

Comment: @MikeBrant fixed. And added my current live log buttons in there for you to see the connection bw ajax.js and index.php

Comment: From what I can see, I don't understand why you would be doing the AJAX request as a POST (GET should be fine, though this is not realy a problem). I still don;t see where logtail.php is going to generate any output at all.  I would think you would need to either call the function or simply not use a function here at all.  So when you look at the request/response activities in something like Firebug, are you at least seeing the requests being made against the server and getting a 200 response?

Comment: @MikeBrant yes when I call the function within logtail.php itself, the array displays its contents in the browser. This is how I know that the function actually works. I just don't know where to call the function in my js or ajax in order to get the information to display in the div on my page. There are multiple other functions that filter the same way but with different regexes, that's why I believe ajax is needed to trigger each filter with separate buttons, maybe a textbox, or even a drop-down menu. Ideas?

Comment: AJAX in and of itself will not call a specific function in PHP to execute.  It will simply execute the logtail.php script which need to know how to product output on its own.  For starters, just add a line like this at the top of logtail.php `dateTimeFilter();` That will execute your function give you your `print_r()` output.  If you need to execute different functions within the script, you probably need to use AJAX to pass GET or POST parameters to logtail.php to tell it what to run.  For example use url of `logtail.php?f=dateTimeFilter`.

Comment: And then have logic in PHP to tell it look at `$_GET['f']` to determine the name of the function to call. and call the appropriate function.  The bottom line is that you will need to have some way of suggesting the PHP function to call (and any parameters it needs) by passing data via GET or POST.

Comment: @MikeBrant that was super helpful advice. Sorry for lack of clarity on my part. I will try that now and post back if I have any success. Thank you!

Comment: Definitely just make sure you are getting the PHP page itself working before you really worry about getting into the AJAX stuff.  You could just as easily set a meta-refresh or javascript page reload every X seconds on the page and reload the data, since you will be in essence reloading the entire content each time.  I would think you would only REALLY need AJAX if you wanted to incrementally load new log entries into the page.

Comment: @MikeBrant that's what my initial goal was and I got that working in the beginning when I was just grabbing the entire syslog file. Once I started | grep-ing certain regexes it starting giving me empty arrays instead of pulling the info I was able to pull with the regex directly in the terminal. Plus I need multiple filters anyway so I had to rework that whole concept.

Comment: @MikeBrant I made a big edit with some new questions based on your input from yesterday. Time sensitive project so I could use some more guidance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would go further than simple pooling. I would pipe logs to some script. Lets say info log

```
 *.info                        |/somescript.php
```

And here I would do real time with [Strophe](http://strophe.im/) and [Php XMPP](http://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/).

Tell me what you think?

Comment: I understand your thought about that and appreciate your input greatly, but the problem is that I don't want to store this information into memory. I need to simply drop the syslog info into a filtered array and display its contents in the div on my javascript page when the function is called.

Comment: The info is gonna be view live in the browser. This isn't for my personal logging needs.